# Why can I play videos from my app bundle but not videos that were downloaded to the file system?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avplayerviewcontroller

My objective is to read a video media I downloaded and stored to my iOS device file system. Unfortunately, the video player stalls with the following code:

```swift
    @IBAction func playVideo(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if let video = detailItem {
            do {
                let url = try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory,
                                                      in: .userDomainMask,                                                                       
                                                      appropriateFor: nil,
                                                      create: false)
                  .appendingPathComponent(video.uuid)
                debugPrint("url: \(url)")

                // Create an AVPlayer, passing it the HTTP Live Streaming URL.
                let player = AVPlayer(url: url)

                // Create a new AVPlayerViewController and pass it a reference to the player.
                let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
                controller.player = player

                // Modally present the player and call the player's play() method when complete.
                present(controller, animated: true) {
                    player.play()
                }
            } catch {
                print("Error: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
```

I assumed it was a video format problem and the codec of my video wasn't supported.

But, when I bundle the exact same video within the app, and switch to this code, everything works fine:

```swift
    @IBAction func playVideo(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "myvideo", withExtension: "mp4")!

//        if let video = detailItem {
            do {
//                let url = try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory,
//                                                                        in: .userDomainMask,
//                                                                        appropriateFor: nil,
//                    create: false).appendingPathComponent(video.uuid)
                debugPrint("url: \(url)")

                // Create an AVPlayer, passing it the HTTP Live Streaming URL.
                let player = AVPlayer(url: url)

                // Create a new AVPlayerViewController and pass it a reference to the player.
                let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
                controller.player = player

                // Modally present the player and call the player's play() method when complete.
                present(controller, animated: true) {
                    player.play()
                }
            } catch {
                print("Error: \(error)")
            }
//        }
    }
```

I have no idea what I am missing here and could get some help.

**EDIT:** The code in charge of the download is here:

```swift
        let downloadTask = URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: video.downloadURL, completionHandler: { (tempPathURL, urlResponse, error) in
            guard let tempPathURL = tempPathURL else {
                return
            }

            do {
                let documentsDirectoryURL = try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory,
                                                                        in: .userDomainMask,
                                                                        appropriateFor: nil,
                                                                        create: false)
                try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: tempPathURL, to: documentsDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent(video.uuid))
            } catch {
                print("Error: \(error)")
            }
        })
        downloadTask.resume()
```

Comment: Can't really help without seeing the code you're using to write the video to your documents folder.

Comment: @clawesome very fair point ‍♂️ — The code in charge of downloading and moving the file is here: https://github.com/dirtyhenry/arzhig-ios/blob/master/arzhig-ios/VideosCoordinator.swift#L30

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong URL for playing downloaded video. Please check your code carefully and notice that you are using the documents directory URL for the player, instead of the actual video.

Comment: I'm not, cf `.appendingPathComponent(video.uuid)`.

Comment: Sorry. Did you check if the video file at that URL exists after moving, but before playing?

Comment: Yes, when using the simulator, I can even find the file with Finder and play it with QuickTime player on my Mac.

Comment: Did you try observing the player's "status" property using KVO? And then print the player's "error" property when its status changes? That might give you more info on why it's not playing.

Answer (score 0):

you should use fileURLWithPath to run video from app files, like this:

```
func PlayVideo() {

    let docPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]

    let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: docPath).appendingPathComponent("IMG_3039.mp4"))

    let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
    controller.player = player

    self.present(controller, animated: true) {
        player.play()
    }
}
```

Comment: This will end up building the same URL. Cf. this gist that prints "Same URL? true" https://gist.github.com/dirtyhenry/ced0aef8a354f80c22e4a8b6ff3e06b2

Comment: i know will give the same result but you must use URL(fileURLWithPath:) to tell the AVPlayer is file not url stream